# Kotlin - How does Boolean? in if expression works on bytecode

Tags: kotlin, bytecode

I know the idiom for consuming nullable Booleans in Kotlin is:

```
fun nullableBoolean(b: Boolean?) {
    if (b == true) {
        println("is true")
    }
}
```

I'm curious about what happens under the hood. This is the interesting part of the generated bytecode for this function:

```
public final static nullableBoolean(Ljava/lang/Boolean;)V
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    LINENUMBER 4 L0
    ALOAD 0
    ICONST_1
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Boolean.valueOf (Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.areEqual (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    IFEQ L1
    ...
```

I can see that `Intrinsics.areEqual` does a null check. But I don't understand what happens with the call to `java/lang/Boolean.valueOf` when the reference is `null`

Comment: @cricket_007 No you can't

Comment: @cricket_007 as mentioned you can't because `b` can be null so unless we use `==` or handle the nullable somehow (like using the _elvis operator_) it won't  compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Boolean.valueOf` is being called on the constant `true` in order to create a boxed Boolean object. This is then compared to the one passed to the function.